# How can I build a simple "Smartwatch" with Arduino Pro Mini and Display?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-pro-mini, time

I want to know how I can build a simple "Smartwatch" with an Arduino Pro Mini and a Display with a size from maybe 1,5" what Display should I use for Touch and color?

I only want simple things like synchonising the time with my Smartphone trough a HC-06 Bluetooth Module.

Comment: Please tell us what display you eventually end up using, especially it it's not one already listed at http://www.opencircuits.com/Watch_display .

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to make a watch you'll need a RTC (Real Time Clock) this can take the form of breakout board, or you can build the circuit yourself. The RTC is needed if you want the mini to display the time. The mini (in fact, most micros) have no internal clock (though they may have a crystal that can simulate time keeping, but this isn't as useful if you want the time)

It sounds like you want an OLED display. They come in watch-like sizes. There are a few small ones. None are touch displays. I have seen larger touch displays. Maybe combine an OLED with a clear capacitive surface?

Comment: Yes but I'd like to synchronice the time my Smartphone is showing and is there no small oled Display with 1.5" with Touch ?